# error: "Found installation Canary" while installing CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, installation

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation canary. 
This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process.
Please post to forum or JIRA. thrown in 
C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\Civi\Core\InstallationCanary.php
 on line 53
```

I am getting above error when I tried to start CIVICRM?

I am not able to go forward.

Can any body guide me?

Comment: It would help if you would state which version of CiviCRM you are trying to install or use? Have you done the installation yourself?

Comment: I am trying to install 4.7 ver.

Comment: Wordpress 4.4.2,

Answer (score 1):

Shashikant,

Were you able to complete the installation mentioned at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Wordpress ?

Kurund

Comment: Yes I could do it successfully. Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you visit [yoursite]/install.php ?

Cheerio,

John